# Не работают таймеры Unity3D в экземплярах класса

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой реализации простой работы оружия на движке Unity, а именно проблема с реализацией таймеров Invoke и IEnumerators. Суть в том, что любое оружие, которое держит в руках персонаж - это экземпляр класса, в котором содержится информация о его работе, а так же методы, через который идет взаимодействие с оружием. Экземпляр класса получается не через объекты, размещенные на сцене, а через импортированного пространства имен, в котором хранится сам класс с оружием (и класс, через которой
это оружие персонаж получает).

(Весь предоставленный код лишь фрагмент, касающийся поставленного вопроса)
Выглядит это примерно так.

ActorSystem.cs (Размещается на объекте, который является персонажем)

````
``` 
using UnityEngine;
using WeaponSystem; // Пространство имен, в котором содержится класс оружия и класс для его получения 

Weapon pistol; // Класс оружия

void Start()
{
    pistol = WeaponPrefab.SimplePistol(); // Получаем новый экземпляр оружия
}
```
````

WeaponSystem.cs (Нигде не размещается, лишь числится в папке проекта)

````
```
using UnityEngine;

namespace WeaponSystem
{
    public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
    {
        bool canShot;
        float shotOffset;

        public Weapon(string name)
        {
            /*
                Представим что, здесь конструктор загружает информацию     конкретного оружия из файла
            */

        }

        public void Shot()
        {
            /*
                Махинация со стрельбой. Подсчитывает патроны, создает пульки, издает пиф-паф.

            */

        }

    }

    public class WeaponPrefab
    {
        public Weapon SimplePistol() { return new Weapon(simplePistol); }

    }

}
```
````

И проблема как раз в самих этих таймеров. Сама загрузка оружия проходит адекватно, все переменные имеют свои значения, полученные в конструкторе. Пробовал я делать через IEnumerator и через Invoke, которые
вызываются из метода Shot класса Weapon.

// Invoke

````
```
private void PermissionForShot(){ canShot = true; }

public void Shot()
{
    canShot = false;
    Invoke("PermissionForShot", shotOffset);
    // this.Invoke("PermissionForCanShot", 3); тоже не получается
}
```
````

//IEnumerator

````
```
private IEnumerators WaitForShot()
{
    canShot = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(shotOffset);
}

public void Shot()
{
    IEnumerator corShot = WaitForShot();
    StartCoroutine(corShot);
}
```
````

В обоих случиях компилируется правильно, но при запуске ошибка "NullReferenceException" выскакивает при вызове этих самых таймеров. То есть, при Invoke или StartCoroutine.
Объясните тугодуму в чем мог быть неправ) Да и корректно ли использовать таймеры в классе, который, по идеи, будет иметь множество экземпляров.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в классе `WeaponSystem.cs` вызвана тем, что он наследуется от `MonoBehaviour`. Следовательно, его инициализация вида `new Weapon(simplePistol);` неправильная. Экземпляр `WeaponSystem` обязательно должен располагаться на объекте (`gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(WeaponSystem))`) и только после этого вызывать метод загрузки информации (перенести реализацию из конструктора)